# Cannot import name 'f1' from 'torchmetrics.functional

Tags: python, metrics

```
from torchmetrics.functional import f1
```

I got the following error while trying to import f1 from the torchmetrics module.

[image]

I installed the torchmetrics module like this:

```
!pip install torchmetrics
```

But the problem persists.

Comment: The [docs](https://torchmetrics.readthedocs.io/en/stable/classification/f1_score.html#f1score) suggest that the name of the class is `F1Score`. As a friendly note, it is better to copy and past errors into the question as text rather than as an image.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this code snippet will be helpful

````
from torchmetrics import F1Score
target = torch.tensor([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2])
preds = torch.tensor([0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1])
f1 = F1Score(num_classes=3)
f1(preds, target)```
````

Comment: I've tried from torchmetrics import F1Score and it worked. It also works when I try another metric as accuracy from torchmetrics import accuracy.

Comment: https://torchmetrics.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html just read documentation here